# python reg ex to include missing commas

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to ensure an string to have comma separated values. The strings I read may have space separated values.

- Some commas might be missing in my input strings, That is if any space separated values exist without comma, I have to include a comma
- I should not make any change to the strings within single quotes or double quotes. these quoted values can include any alpha numeric except quotes.

an example string is:

```
""" 1, ' unchanged 1' " unchanged  2 "  2.009, -2e15 """
```

I should include commas after 'not this1' and after " not this 2 ".

So my resultant string should be:

```
"""1,' unchanged 1'," unchanged 2 ",2.009,-2e15"""
```

I have been trying `s1|s2|(s3)` type regular expressions. But was unable to accomplish the task.

Strings can have different number of values to be comma separated.

Comment: Do you mean something like `(re.sub(r"([\'\"].*?[\'\"])\s", r"\1, ",s)`?

Comment: Different strings can have different number of values to be comma separated. For eg. if I changed the string to """ 1, ' unchanged 1' " unchanged  2 "  2, 2  45""" Padraic's re doesn't seem to work.

Comment: PyParsing might be a more readable way to do this, if that is an option...?

Comment: I will be reading these lines from a file which has lines in the range of several dozens to about 100k. If PyParsing does not significantly makes my whole process slower, it is an option for me.

Comment: what should `""" 1, ' unchanged 1' " unchanged 2 " 2, 2 45"""` output?

Comment: """ 1 , ' unchanged 1 ',  " unchanged  2 ", 2, 2, 45 """

Comment: do you really want spaces before a comma?

Comment: No. I will edit that line in the question.

Comment: How is `"""1,` a valid field ? There is no congruity to the string definitions, let alone fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier use findall, str.join and str.strip, finding the strings between quotes first then all non-whitespace:

```
s = """ 1, ' unchanged 1' " unchanged  2 "  2.009, -2e15 3"""

r = re.compile("[\'\"].*?[\'\"]|\S+")
print(", ".join([x.strip(",") for x in r.findall(s)]))

1, ' unchanged 1', " unchanged  2 ", 2.009, -2e11, ' unchanged 1', " unchanged  2 ", 2.009, -2e15, 35, 3
```

If you don't want any space after the comma:

```
print(",".join([x.strip(",") for x in r.findall(s)]))
1,' unchanged 1'," unchanged  2 ",2.009,-2e15,3
```

Comment: additional requirement came up: There might not be spaces in between comma separated values. for eq. my example string can be """ 1,' unchanged 1' " unchanged  2 "  2.009, -2e15 """ (without the space in between first 1 and the comma). There may be several comma separated values together without any spaces before or after the comma.

Comment: However, there will be one or more spaces in between two non-comma separated values.

Comment: Also, there can be commas in quoted or double quoted strings. but those should not be altered. for eg. """667000, ,"0 2",100.0 '   spa ces         ' , ,10""" should return me """667000, ,"0 2",100.0,'   spa ces         ', ,10""" .

Comment: I will have a look when i get back on my laptop

Comment: Padraic: Whenever you have some time

Answer (score 2):

PyParsing will definitely not be the fastest way to run this, but it is perhaps the fastest way to write it ;-)

```
from pyparsing import *

STRING = sglQuotedString | dblQuotedString
NONSTRING = Word(alphanums + '.-')
line = OneOrMore(STRING | NONSTRING | Suppress(',')) + lineEnd


def insert_commas(s):
    values = line.parseString(s).asList()
    return ", ".join(values)


s1 = """1, ' unchanged 1' " unchanged  2 "  2, 2"""
s2 = """1, ' unchanged 1', " unchanged 2 " ,  2, 2"""
s3 = """ 1, ' unchanged 1' " unchanged 2 " 2, 2 45"""
s4 = """1, 67.90e-34 67.90E-34 7.9093339333 2, 2 """

print insert_commas(s1)
print insert_commas(s2)
print insert_commas(s3)
print insert_commas(s4)
```

which prints

```
1, ' unchanged 1', " unchanged  2 ", 2, 2
1, ' unchanged 1', " unchanged 2 ", 2, 2
1, ' unchanged 1', " unchanged 2 ", 2, 2, 45
1, 67.90e-34, 67.90E-34, 7.9093339333, 2, 2
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing a solution. I have to say the numbers here can be floats. for eg. """1, 67.90e-34 67.90E-34 7.9093339333   2, 2 """.

Comment: I will check the performance in terms of time consumption on tomorrow. I have no access to a large file at this moment.

Comment: thanks thebjorn. Let me check the performance tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: fwiw, I'm getting 5185 lines/sec on a decent i7 (not including anything but the parsing), compared to 185430 lines/sec with @Padraic Cunningham's regex solution -- his version can't handle missing spaces though """ 1' unchanged 1'" unchanged 2 "2, 2 45""" ;-)

Comment: thebjorn: In this case I will have no spaces missing in between two values. if so I will have to use this approach. Thanks a lot for evaluating performance for me. I think I will go for Padraic's solution because of the speed and the current scope.

Comment: The "no spaces" was a (bad) attempt at a joke.  You should definitely go for Padraic's solution.