# Python regex split comma or space separated string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have shown an example of the input string and the output string I need to have. The numbers and strings can be in any order and those can have any number or any string (e.g. 'THIS' can be some other string)

I need following output

```
["'5'", "'THIS'", "'/,'", "'4.2560'", "'0.34000E-01'"]
```

for all following input strings:

```
""" 5,'THISMORETHAN4','/,',4.2560,0.34000E-01 """
""" 5,'THIS','/,',4.2560,0.34000E-01 """
"""5 , 'THIS' , '/,' , 4.2560 , 0.34000E-01 """
""" '5'  'THIS' '/,' '4.2560' '0.34000E-01' """
""" 5,'THIS','this','/,',4.2560,0.34000E-01 """
""" 5,'THIS','/,',4.2560,0.34000E-01 """
```

This is a continuation of [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969459/python-reg-ex-to-include-missing-commas).

1. The strings can be comma separated or space separated. There may be
   or may not be spaces before or after a splitting comma.
2. sub strings in single quotes may have special characters within (e.g. '/,' as shown above)

Comment: Do you really need those `'` quotes in your output? Why all your input strings start with `"""` and end with `"""`?

Comment: NO ! that is optional

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't just using a csv reader?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. I've based on Padraic's answer for the previous question that I have mentioned. I've but so far I've failed to get it done for comma separated strings. If it is only space separated or comma separated, it becomes easier. However, I'm unable to do right for both.

Comment: @  polpak: some strings are space separated. can I still use the csv reader in python for both comma and space separated text?

Comment: nope, you can only specify one delimiter using the csv lib, even if you could there is way more to your question than just separating the data. Also are there actually commas in the substrings? i.e `'/,'`?

Comment: Yes Padraic, sub strings can have commas within.

Answer (score 0):

As an improved version of Padraic Cunningham's solution from your previous question, the regex [`(["']).*?\1(?<!\\["'])|[^\r\n\t\f ,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/lJ5zN4/3) will capture all your fields.

The first part (`(["']).*?\1(?<!\\["'])`) now also works with fields like `'asdf"'` because the sourrounding quote characters have to be the same. It also works with escaped quotes because `(?<!\\["'])` asserts that there is no backslash before the second quote.

If the first part doesn't match (i.e. there is no string surrounded by quotes), the second part (`[^\r\n\t\f ,]+`) matches everything that is not a whitespace or a comma.  So it will ignore your delimiters but match everything else.

```
import re

rows = [""" 5,'THISMORE"THAN4','/,',4.2560,0.34000E-01 """,
        #              ^ added quote character here
        """ 5,'TH\\'IS','/,',4.2560,0.34000E-01 """,
        #          ^ added escaped quote here
        """5 , 'THIS' , '/,' , 4.2560 , 0.34000E-01 """,
        """ '5'  'THIS' '/,' '4.2560' '0.34000E-01' """,
        """ 5,'THIS','this','/,',4.2560,0.34000E-01 """,
        """ 5,'THIS','/,',4.2560,0.34000E-01 """]

pattern = re.compile(r'(["\']).*?\1(?<!\\["\'])|[^\r\n\t\f ,]+')

result = [[m.group(0).strip('"\'') for m in pattern.finditer(row)]
          for row in rows]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Prints:

```
[['5', 'THISMORE"THAN4', '/,', '4.2560', '0.34000E-01'],
 ['5', "TH\\'IS", '/,', '4.2560', '0.34000E-01'],
 ['5', 'THIS', '/,', '4.2560', '0.34000E-01'],
 ['5', 'THIS', '/,', '4.2560', '0.34000E-01'],
 ['5', 'THIS', 'this', '/,', '4.2560', '0.34000E-01'],
 ['5', 'THIS', '/,', '4.2560', '0.34000E-01']]
```

What will still be problematic are unquoted fields that contain spaces within a line that has comma separation. Therefore

```
'hello there, "I actually", have, 5, fields'
```

Will result in:

```
['hello','there','I actually','have','5','fields']
```

Do you have that in your data?

Answer (score -1):

This regular expression works on all your test cases

```
(\d)\W*\'([A-Z]{0,4})\w*\'.*(\/)\W*(\d*\.\d*)\W*(\d*\.\d*E-\d*)
```

Comment: I can explain more in a bit if you want